# Would a dead character know which resurrection spell was used on it?

Tags: dnd-5e, resurrection

If a character was killed and then a druid attempted to resurrect them, would the character know which resurrection spell was used? I'm primarily asking because I have a character who was killed and would want to be revived but the only character in our party for that game was a druid who was not a fan of my race (tiefling). She would want to come back but not if the druid attempted to do so with [Reincarnate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reincarnate) as she would not want the 97% chance to not come back as a tiefling.

Note for any potential "ask your DM" answerers: I'm asking about a campaign that has already ended so instead of answers like that please say what *you* would do as the DM in this situation.

Comment: It's interesting that both your question and the duplicate state the title in broad terms but the body questions only specifically *reincarnate*, would you want to make this question more broad to cover all methods of resurrection and then reopen it?

Comment: @Medix2 I would but I don't see why it would ever matter except in the case of reincarnation. Every resurrection spell has the same end result except Reincarnate and similar questions like who cast the spell have their own questions already